# Create any polarisation state with two quarter wave plates?

Tags: polarization

new to this so be kind.

I have a question regarding polarisation of light. I got taught that in order to transform any arbitrary input state (fully polarised) into any arbitrary output state in polarisation, you need two quarter and a half wave plate (in order QHQ).
However, I've been doing some simulations with Jones matrices and it seems like it is enough to have two quarter wave plates. Or at least, I couldn't find an input state that I couldn't move to any arbitrary output state. I am probably missing the needle in the haystack here.

Could anyone tell me a combo (input/output)that won't work? I am using py_pol to calculate and plot the Jones matrices.

Thanks
Markus

PS: happy to clarify anything that I might have missed to formulate the problem.

Comment: What combinations have you been able to realize so far? It might be that any input/output combination consisting of pure linear or pure circular CAN be realized with two QWP but that you need to consider generic elliptical states to get a counterexample.

Comment: I have been focussing on H, V, D, A, L, R. I figured if I cover all 'poles' of the Poincare sphere it should be valid for states in between too ...

Comment: I don't think it's the case. I think you should try to convert any input polarization to any output polarization in the case the both input and output are off the equator and not on the poles. I do think H, V, D, A, L, R can all be inter-converted. I don't think general elliptical polarizations can, but I've personally never seen a proof.

Comment: An interesting exercise: Can you prove that with a QHQ combination you CAN convert any elliptical polarization into any other elliptical polarization? Proving this might help you figure out why you CAN'T do the conversion if you lack the half waveplate.

Comment: I didn't do that math, but conceptional any elliptical polarisation can be made into linear polarisation with a QWP, then any linear can be converted into any other linear with a HWP, and finally any linear can be converted to elliptical again with another QWP. So it feels like if you're missing the HWP, you cannot move on the equator of the Poincare sphere, so you can't subsequently get to arbitrary elliptical again, but I cannot recreate this somehow :)

Comment: we can work this out. First write down the Jones matrix that takes you from an arbitrary polarization (using Dirac notation) $|a\rangle$ to another arbitrary polarization $|b\rangle$. This will be the matrix for the outer-product operator $|b\rangle\langle a|$. Then write down the Jones matrices for the product of QHQ and QQ waveplates. For the latter you should be able to prove the QQ matrix cannot be made to equal $|b\rangle\langle a|$ for some choices of $|a\rangle$ and $|b\rangle$ parametrized by their Jones parameters $\theta$ and $\phi$.